# Choosing Ubuntu distro for Apache server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, azure

I'm gonna host Apache server on Azure VM. For that i got choice of selecting one of following Ubuntu distros. What should i choose, Which one is more stable ?

- Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS
- Ubuntu Server 13.10
- Ubuntu Server 12.10
- Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In first, it in depends on quality of your system source like CPU, RAM, ... .

In addition, If you have time about 2 month, base on the term *LTS (Long Time Support)* i suggest you wait for Ubuntu server 14.04, else Ubuntu server 12.04 can be the best choice for you.

Comment: Waiting is not possible. I need live sever up and running immediately. It has 7GB RAM and 4 virtual cores.

Comment: That's not bad. If you can't wait, download and install Ubuntu 12.04.4. By the way if stability is important in services, you can choose Debian 7.4.

Comment: OK, Good luck and enjoy it.

Comment: For stable production servers always go for LTS (if it's Ubuntu). You will get Updates and support for 5 years, with the regular version you only get updates for 18 months so you will be forced to upgrade your server to a newer version quite more often.

Comment: Ya, Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS also available for VM images. But its still a beta. So have go with 12.04.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Non-LTS versions of Ubuntu are now on a 9-month support lifecycle.